# "This user has no earned bounties" might be correct but sounds... weird

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, wording, information-display

In the user profile page, there are the following sentences when the user has no questions or answers:

> This user has not answered any questions

> This user has not asked any questions

So far so good. Also, when the user has no active bounties:

> This user has no active bounties

Still good. However, when viewing *offered* or *earned* bounties:

> This user has no offered bounties

> This user has no earned bounties

While I understand the reason (making it consistent with the *active* message) I think that  while in the summary view it's better be consistent with the no questions/no answers message:

>This user has not offered any bounties

> This user has not earned any bounties

[Live test case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138426/peterino?tab=topactivity) (just a random inactive user :))

Comment: Where's Jeff with his giant S when you need him? ;P

Comment: @Yannis yeah, I waited until he and his giant S are away! ;)

Comment: "This user has no offered bounties" sounds more neutral than "This user has not offered *any* bounties".

Comment: @Antony maybe, but it's still not consistent with the other texts.

Comment: @Antony The difference sentence is that the first is using the simple present tense, while the other one is using the present perfect tense. In such case, the present perfect tense is more correct, as the sentence is talking about the past, but saying something that is also true for the present.